# Body background image opacity

Tags: html, css, image, opacity

I've been trying to add opacity to the body background image of a web page. I've tried almost everything including adding the opacity tag to the body in css. Nothing is working. Please help people!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: this wan't be the answer of your question. but for instance maybe it help you:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pseudo element on the body.

```
body::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/250/000/fff);
  opacity: .2;
}
```

https://codepen.io/cloudandculture/pen/wNeWwm

Comment: According to the CSS standards, you should use `::after` (double colon is recommended) and not `:after`

Comment: Thank you @Helenesh. 

Let the record state! ::double colon for pseudo elements, :single colon for pseudo class